# Play Framework 2.3 :Call Scala object from Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework

With Play 2.2, in a java application, I'm using a Scala object from my Java Global class :

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
  MyRegistry$ myRegistry = MyRegistry$.MODULE$;
...
}
```

In my 'app' folder, I have a Scala object defined

```
object MyRegistry {

 ...

}
```

I'm trying to migrate to Play 2.3, and this is not working anymore

```
[ERROR] /home/descottl/projects/ads/kelkooAdService/app/Global.java:[36,30] cannot   find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable MyRegistry$
[ERROR] location: class Global
```

Do I need to change something in my build settings to make Java and Scala work together?

I've tried to put this in my Build.scala file :

```
lazy val root = (project in file("..")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

But it does not slove the issue

Thanks

Comment: In what package is `MyRegistry`?

Comment: In the default package, like the Global object

Comment: I've tried to put it in another one , if I do mypackage.MyRegistry$ I have a 'package mypackage does not exist' error

Comment: Where is the file that contains `MyRegistry` located in the project tree?

Comment: Directly under app, like Global.java

Comment: Is this happening in activator/sbt? I can't make this fail, whether it's in the same package/folder or not.

Comment: Yes, with SBT but we have some conf strangeness (due to compatibility with other build systems), I'll post the answer when I find why it fails, thanks a lot